# (Excel) Check if values are the same and if they are, adjusting the adjacent cell

Tags: excel

What I'm attempting to do is make a list of dates in one column, and have today's date in a specific cell (`=TODAY`). If the date in column B matches what's in my specified cell (`G12`), I want the cell to the direct RIGHT of that dated cell from column B to be adjusted to the same value as what's in another cell (`F13`).

So if today's date is 5/17, my function or solution would check column B for that date, find the cell that has the same date, and then adjust the value of the cell to the right of that date to whatever would be the same as cell (`F13`). So if cell (`F13`) has the value of 56, my spreadsheet would check today's date, find that cell in column B and adjust the cell to the right of it to be the same as `F13` (56).

I hope that makes sense. I have some experience in VBA if that's what is needed to accomplish this. I'd like to make it automated as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoFilter to filter for today's date on column B and if there are visible cells, set column C to the value in F13.

```
With worksheets("sheet1")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=date
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                .specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).offset(0,1) = .parent.cells(13, "F").value2
            End If
        End With
    End With
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: So, I used this following code to acomplish what I needed. The only trouble now is that it adjusts values across about 5 cells across. So, it puts the correct value from F13 where it belongs but also fills out the next 4 cells going across with the same value. I'm not sure why or how to correct it. @jeeped

Comment: Bump back. The answer is pretty straight-forward. You need to resize and possibly offset the target cells that will receive the value from F13. If you cannot even make an attempt at that then you do not understand the code already provided and solving your new issue is kind of pointless since you won't try to understand the solution.

Comment: Let me try to run through this then to check my understanding.
1. You decide on sheet1.
2. If autofiltermode is on, then turn it off.
3. With the A1 Cell as the current region, autofilter field #2, which I assume would be the B column?
4. This is where it gets a little more harry for me. Keep in mind when i mentioned I have SOME experience. I may not understand all code...

If somebody can kindly walk me through the rest of what exactly is happening, i'd appreciate it.